# How to get the contour of an image in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape

I have an image of a human brain, but I only need the contour of it; its outer shape and not everything that's on the inside of the brain. I tried using Trace Bitmap, but I still got the inside of the brain. Hope my question is clear and thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Welcome to **GD.SE** - *Please* look through **[tour]** to get a sense of our community – who we are and what we’re about. *Then* look over **[ask]** and **[answer]** a question to see what makes a good query here, *and* how best to frame it. We ***do*** ask that questions show their *effort*: show us what you tried and failed; tell us why the straightforward approach won't work; illustrate your question with sketches, screenshots or examples. I'm wondering why can't you just draw the contour? Consider [edit]ing  your question to show us your efforts. Thanks!

Comment: Usually that would be a manual operation - using the Bézier Tool (aka Pen Tool) to draw around the image, unless you can first fill the raster image a solid colour in a raster image editor, such as GIMP, but it's probably more trouble than it's worth TBH.

Comment: Perhaps you could find a silhouette image of a brain instead, then an auto trace would be easy.

Answer (score 2):

Using the Trace Bitmap feature provides a number of options.
There may be an easier method than this, but consider to adjust the Brightness Cutoff threshold value with the Live Update ticked.

[image: brain trace image]

There's a small artifact in the lower left corner, probably left from my hasty edit, but the result is a solid shape. You can then remove fill, add or adjust stroke as desired.

If your computer is slow and/or you have a large number of objects in your image and document, you may find the Live Preview to be burdensome.

Comment: thx for the help, this seems like a fast method.